# nodejs express.router with parameters

Tags: node.js, express, router

## Problem

I am using a nodejs application with the express module. To have a structure I split the routes into a extern routes.js. I want give this route.js next to the req and res parameters some other parameters who will be needed. But I don´t know how I can do it.

## Index.js

```
const app = express();
        app.use(session({
        secret: uuidv4(),
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true
    }));
    app.use(helmet());
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));
    app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/site/static')));
    app.use('/', routes);
```

## routes.js

```
module.exports = (function() {
        'use strict';
        let router = require('express').Router();
        router.get('/', (req, res) => {
            if(!req.session || req.session.key !== loginkey) {
                res.redirect('/login');
            } else {
                res.redirect('dashboard');
            };
        });
        router.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
            if(req.session && req.session.key === loginkey) {
                helper.render(req, res, "sites/dashboard");
            } else {
                res.redirect('/');
            };
        });
        router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
            log.LogLine(3, "GET /login");
            helper.render(req, res, "sites/login");
        });

        router.get('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
            log.LogLine(3, "GET /logout");
            if (req.session) {
                req.session.destroy(function(err) {
                    if(err) {
                        return next(err);
                    } else {
                        return res.redirect('/');
                    };
                });
            };
        });
        return router;
    })();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass something along from **index.js** to your routes in **routes.js** then you can do the following.

In your **routes.js**, you could accept some parameters:

```
module.exports = function(arg1, arg2) {

  let router = require('express').Router();

  router.get('/', (req, res) => {

    // You can now use arg1 and arg2 here

  });

  // ...

  return router;

};
```

*Note, you'll need to remove your IIFE to stop the function from being immediately invoked.*

Then in **index.js**, you can invoke the function and pass in whatever you want:

```
app.use('/', routes('something', 'something else'));
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ah I forget to remove the iife. But doesn't the router need the iife? I am sure if I will remove it I got a timeout. But I will try this later that day.

Comment: You’ll be invoking the function in **index.js** instead so you won’t need the IIFE.

Comment: Thanks. Works pretty well!